# Geometric interpretation of adding two hyperplanes

Tags: vector-spaces, affine-geometry

maybe a bit of a novice question, but I would like to get a geometric interpretation of the addition of two hyperplanes. You can interpret a hyperplane described by: 
 $ax -b = 0$ where $a,x \in R^{d}$ and $b \in R$
 as 
 $(x-p)a = 0$ s.t. $pw = b$, where $p \in R^{d}$. 
If I understand correctly, this intuitively means you translate the hyperplane $ax=0$ by a vector $p$.
I would like to know how you can describe this vector $p$ in the case of adding two hyperplanes: 

$(a_1 x - b_1) + (a_2x - b_2) = 0 = (a_1 + a_2)x - p_1a_1 -p_2a_2 $

So, I would like to describe this hyperplane in the same way as the previous, namely the translation of the hyperplane $(a_1+a_2)x=0$ by some vector $p^`$, but I cant figure out what this $p^`$ would be.. Is there some nice way of describing $-(a_1p_1+a_2p_2)$ as a factor of $(a_1+a_2)$ such that we can translate the hyperplane by this vector?

Comment: You keep switching between $a$ and $w$ or $a_1, a_2$ and $w_1, w_2$. In all cases $w = a, w_1 = a_1, w_2 = a_2$, so there is absolutely no reason to do this.

Comment: Also, $x\in \Bbb R^d$ and $a \in M_{k,d}(\Bbb R)$, the set of all $k \times d$ matrices with real entries. $M_{k,d}(\Bbb R)$ can be identified with $\Bbb R^{k\times d}$, but particularly for novices (which you evidently are since you don't know how dimensions work), there are good reasons to use the matrix notation and think of it as something a little different, except in the special case of $M_{1,d}(\Bbb R) = \Bbb R^d$ (single column matrices are also vectors). It is often okay to consider row matrices as vectors: $M_k,1 = \Bbb R^k$, but generally want to think of them as a different space.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the notation now. I also swapped some plus and minus signs. To be clear, $a$, $x$ and $p$ all have the same dimension and $b$ is still just a scalar.

Comment: So now $a$ is a vector instead of a matrix and we are taking an inner product? That limits the hyperplanes to those having codimension $1$ (i.e., only to hyperplanes of dimension $d-1$). Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes that is what I am after.

Comment: Specifically, if $p_1$ is the displacement of the hyperplane $a_1 x = 0$ that gives $ (x - p_1)a_1 = 0$, I would like to know the displacement $p^`$ of the hyperplane $(a_1 + a_2)x = 0$ that produces the hyperplane $((x - p_1)a_1) + ((x-p_2)a_2) = 0$.

Comment: So... did you not read my answer, or just not understand it?

Comment: As I don't see how it answers my question I probably don't understand it.

Comment: The highlights are (1) any point on the combined plane will work for $p$. So there will be multiple solutions. You can choose any of them. (2) In general, you find $p$ by finding a solution to the system of equations $(a_1+a_2)p= b_1 + b_2$ (3) in general, there is no geometric shortcut that will give you the answer (4) in the special case that the two planes are parallel ($a_1 = a_2$), the point $(b_1+b_2)/2$ will work. (5) in the special case that the two planes intersect, you can solve the simpler system $a_1p=b_1\quad a_2p = b_2$.

Comment: Thank you that makes it a bit more clear. It gets even more involved as these hyperplanes lie in hyperbolic space for my use case, so there are infinitely many parallel lines for a given line. I guess that makes the problem even more complicated. Either way, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mistake in thinking that there is some particular $p$ that must be identified for $ax - b = 0$ to be changed to $a(x - p) = 0$ ($a$ is a matrix and $x$ is a vector, so $ax \ne xa$, in fact, $xa$ is not even defined unless $a$ is $1\times d$). But in fact, *every point on the hyperplane defined by $ax - b = 0$ can be used as $p$*.

If $x$ and $p$ are any two points on the hyperplane, then $$\begin{matrix} &ax - b = 0\\-&ap - b = 0\\\hline&ax - ap = 0\\&a(x - p) = 0\end{matrix}$$

Conversely, if $a(x - p) = 0$ we can distribute: $ax - ap = 0$ and set $b = ap$ to get $ax - b = 0$. Since $ap = b$, we have $ap - b = 0$, which says that $p$ must be a point on the hyperplane as well.

---

Now as to your question, First note that this "sum" of hyperplanes does not generally contain either of the original hyperplanes, but only their intersection. If $a_1x + b_1 = 0$ then for $a_1x + b_1 + a_2x + b_2 = 0$ to be true, we must have $a_2x + b_2 = 0$. That is, for points of $a_1x + b_1 + a_2x + b_2 = 0$ to be one either of the two original hyperplanes, they have to be on both.

Since any point on the combined hyperplane will work for its $p$, and the combined hyperplane includes the intersection of the originals, we could just choose one of the intersection points, assuming any exist: Solve the system of equations $$a_1p = b_1\\a_2p = b_2$$ If $p$ is a solution, then $(a_1 + a_2)(x - p) = 0$ is your combined plane.

Of course, it could easily be that there is no intersection. In this case, the combined plane does not intersection either of the original planes. Before examining that case, I think some examples might be helpful:

Let's look at what happens in $\Bbb R^2$, and set $k = 1$. If $a_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $a_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, and $b_1 = b_2 = 0$, the first hyperplane $L_1$ is vertical axis $x_1 = 0$ and the second $L_2$ is the horizontal axis $x_2 = 0$. However, your "sum" $L_3$ is the equation $x_1 + x_2 = 0$. In more familiar form $y = -x$, the line at angle $-45^\circ$ through $0$.

Suppose we now set the $a_2$ line to be $L_3$, while leaving $a_1$ as the vertical axis. The next line $L_4$ has equation $2x + y = 0$. Setting $a_2$ to the $L_4$ line gives $L_5$ with equation $3x + y = 0$, and so on:
[image]

As you can see, the behavior of the combined lines is not some readily recognizable geometric combination.

What happens if the two planes are parallel: $a_1 = a_2 = a$ but $b_1 \ne b_2$? The combined equation is $2ax - (b_1 + b_2) = 0$ or $$ax - \frac{b_1 + b_2}2 = 0$$
I.e., you get the midplane between them.

What happens if they are skew? Here, you can use gaussian elimination to solve the system of equations $$(a_1 + a_2)p = b_1 + b_2$$. If there were some slick general trick for determining it, that trick would be an easier method of solving such systems, so we can be fairly sure there isn't one. Examining this as skew lines in $\Bbb R^3$ doesn't reveal any evident geometric relationship either (there almost certainly is one, but it will be something esoteric, not obvious).